# cant find sequelize n:m relation tables

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typescript, sqlite, sequelize.js

Im working with typescript and sequelize, and I have the following tables: **Prophet**, **Model** and **Task**, and they all have an n:m relation with each other, so sequelize automatically creates 3 other tables: **modelProphets**, **modelTasks** and **prophetTasks**.
Ive got a simple repository for each one of them, and models and tasks have an extra function in the repo:

```
public findWithoutProphet(): Promise<any> {
    const query = `SELECT models.name FROM models WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT modelProphets.modelName FROM modelProphets WHERE models.name = modelProphets.modelName);`;
    return this.database.rawQuery(query);
}
```

im unit testing every repository function, but the thing is, when I run using the sequelize dialect 'sqlite', everything works fine, but if I change it to my local docker postgres and run it again, an error is thrown during that query, saying 'modelProphets' doesnt exist (or prophetTasks if I run the task one first instead of model). All other repo functions like creating, deleting, updating, finding, everything works fine. I even checked the DB using pgAdmin4 and all the relation tables are there, so...

why sequelize gives me this error with postgresql, when sqlite runs fine? Are the automatic relation tables different for each DB? Should I have a different repository for each DB Im testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with sequelize much but Postgres doesn't work well with capital letters. Put table name into double quotes if you want Postgres to preserve case for names.

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted
>   names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers
>   FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo"
>   and "FOO" are different from these three and each other. (The folding
>   of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the
>   SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper
>   case. Thus, foo should be equivalent to "FOO" not "foo" according to
>   the standard. If you want to write portable applications you are
>   advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.)

from [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

Comment: omg, It actually said "cannot find 'modelprophets' table" (without the capital letters), and I forgot to mention that, thinking it had nothing to do with the problem, but it was that! Thanks for the help!